# Can more than one app be combined into one overall app?

Tags: iphone, web-applications

Rather than create a new app, I would like to hire a programmer to bridge multiple existing apps into one overall app.  For example, a Fishing app that incorporated 3 already published apps from 3 different developers: Map, Compass, and Tide apps.  Of course the venture and profits would be shared amongst all developers...but I would like to know if it is possible?  Are there programming or size limitations to an app?  Are there any significant roadblocks that would make this more difficult than creating an app from scratch?

Comment: In the App Store or on the web? Your web-applications tag makes that a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. While there are some apps on the App Store that really should be contained in one (e.g. like 10 mathematics apps with the same icon, just different lessons), it doesn't make much sense to me to combine 3 apps from separate developers. The only size limitation is the 2GB max for an application, which I doubt will be a problem. If it makes sense for these apps to be made into one, then it shouldn't be that difficult but it depends on how they are going to integrate... I'm assuming you don't mean just letting the user choose between the three at a main screen, which would be kind of pointless.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the programmer to combine those 3 apps, he/she will have to have to source code for those apps, otherwise they have to be recreated from scratch.  Given the source they can be combined into one new large app.

If you're thinking he/she can just write some code to link existing apps together, no, it doesn't work that way, especially on the iPhone.